# Firefox weird behaviours - copying does not work with Gnome

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome, gnome-shell

When using `Firefox`, sometimes my `C-c` is automatically disabled and does nothing after that (copying with `right click -> copy` still works, so does clicking with the `middle mouse button`). Restarting `Firefox` does not help.

Sometimes I also have a curious bug, that the window sometimes *"flickers"*, shows the desktop wallpaper for a fragment of a second, than brings the window back to focus.
I wonder if these weird effects are due to using the `Gnome desktop`, and my guess that it has something to do with the top-bar interfering with `FF`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There are [several "clipboards" in Linux](https://mutelight.org/subtleties-of-the-x-clipboard). Sometimes an application loses the connection with one of them. If you have a clipboard manager/history keeper, it will usually see both clipboards and will copy data between them (to the benefit of applications that only access one). But no, I don't know why FF ceases to talk to the clipboard.